# Integrating NX with JSF

Tags: jsf, nx-workspace

Is it possible to integrate a JSF project with an NX workspace? I am conducting some research but have not found anything so far, and I am wondering if anyone has done this before. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!